# How do you delete a node in linked list when you are given access to only the node

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

My understanding is that in order to delete a node in singly linked list, we need access to the current node and previous node. I have the following logic for it:

```
public SingleNode delete(int val) {

    SingleNode current = head;
    SingleNode prev = head;

    while(current.data != val) {

        if (current.next == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            prev = current;
            current = current.next;
        }

    }

    if(current == head) {
        head = current.next;
    } else {
        prev.next = current.next;
    }

    return current;

}
```

How can I change the code so that I can delete a node in linked list when you are given access to only the current node?

Comment: Hint: It's possible if the node to delete is not the last one.

Answer (score 1):

If only the access to the node to be deleted you could do below, by setting the data and next pointers of next node to current node.

```
public void delete (Node<E> node){
    if (node.next! = null){
        node.data = node.next.data;
        node.next = node.next.next;
    }else{
        node.next = null;
        node.data = null;
    }
```

}

If the data structure defined with sentinel then we don't need the null check, simply change the pointers of data and next pointers of current to next

*Sent from mobile, may contain typo

**UPDATE**

Here is the partial implementation with sentinel

```
public class LinkedList<E> {

    private static class Node<E> {
        E element;
        Node<E> next;

        public Node(E element, Node<E> next) {
            this.element = element;
            this.next = next;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Node [element=" + element + ", next=" + next + "]";
        }

    }

    private int size;
    private Node<E> head; // sentinel
    private Node<E> tail; // sentinel

    public LinkedList() {
        tail = new Node<>(null, null);
        head = new Node<>(null, tail);
    }

    public int size() {
        return this.size;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return this.size == 0;
    }

    public Node<E> head() {
        return head.next;
    }

    public Node<E> tail() {
        // TODO
    }

    public void addFirst(E e) {
        addBetween(head, e, head.next);
    }

    public void addLast(E e) {
        // TODO
    }

    public void addBetween(Node<E> prev, E element, Node<E> next) {
        Node<E> curr = new Node<>(element, next);
        prev.next = curr;
        size++;
    }

    public Node<E> node(E e) {
        Node<E> temp = head;
        while (temp != null) {
            if (temp.element == e) {
                return temp;
            }
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public E delete(Node<E> node) {
        E e = node.element;
        node.element = node.next.element;
        node.next = node.next.next;
        return e;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Node<E> temp = head;
        while (temp != null) {
            sb.append(temp.element + " ");
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<Integer> ll = new LinkedList<>();
        ll.addFirst(10);
        ll.addFirst(20);
        ll.addFirst(30);
        ll.addFirst(40);
        ll.addFirst(50);
        System.out.println("Linked List :: " + ll);
        Node<Integer> node = ll.node(10);
        System.out.println("Node :: " + node);
        System.out.println("Element :: " + ll.delete(node));
        System.out.println("Final List :: " + ll);
    }
}
```

output

```
Linked List :: null 50 40 30 20 10 null 
Node :: Node [element=10, next=Node [element=null, next=null]]
Element :: 10
Final List :: null 50 40 30 20 null
```

Comment: If it's the last Node, you will still have the Node you wanted to delete in the list just with `null` for data. This would be particularly problematic if null data values are allowed in the list.

Comment: Yes agree, but If head and tail has dummy node it won't be a problem

Comment: I'm not convinced by your "make the head / tail into dummy nodes" argument.  You need to provide full details, including code for the insert and lookup operations.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I change the code so that I can delete a node in linked list when you are given access to only the current node?

For a singly-linked list, you cannot remove a node with a given reference unless you have *either* the previous node, *or* you can access the head of the list.

If you have the head, you can find the previous node ... in `O(N)` steps.

There is a way to remove a node by modifying it that works in most cases, but there are various edge cases that make it difficult.  (And it certainly won't work if you need to support concurrent removal and iteration, etcetera.)

Comment: @Saravana - Your code won't work if you are deleting the last (or only) node in the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct node *temp  = node_ptr->next;
node_ptr->data  = temp->data;
node_ptr->next  = temp->next;
free(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

void deleteNode (struct node *node_ptr)

{

struct node *temp = node_ptr->next;

node_ptr->data    = temp->data;

node_ptr->next    = temp->next;

free(temp);

}

The above function delete the node with a single pointer.
The method doesn’t work if the node to be deleted is the last node of the list.